# How to implement the math pow of my postfix algorithm - C

Tags: c, postfix-notation

I have simple algorithm for create postfix in C.

Here is a [sample program](http://www.c-program-example.com/2011/10/c-program-for-infix-to-postfix.html) with my addition to handle `pow`:

```
/***********************************************************
* You can use all the programs on  www.c-program-example.com
* for personal and learning purposes. For permissions to use the
* programs for commercial purposes,
* contact info@c-program-example.com
* To find more C programs, do visit www.c-program-example.com
* and browse!
* 
*                                  Happy Coding
***********************************************************/

#define SIZE 50            /* Size of Stack */
#include <ctype.h>
char s[SIZE];
int top = -1; /* Global declarations */

push(char elem) { /* Function for PUSH operation */
 s[++top] = elem;
}

char pop() { /* Function for POP operation */
 return (s[top--]);
}

int pr(char elem) { /* Function for precedence */
 switch (elem) {
 case '#':
  return 0;
 case '(':
  return 1;
 case '+':
 case '-':
  return 2;
 case '*':
 case '/':
  return 3;
 case '^':
  return 4;
 }
}

main() { /* Main Program */
 char infx[50], pofx[50], ch, elem;
 int i = 0, k = 0;
 printf("\n\nRead the Infix Expression ? ");
 scanf("%s", infx);
 push('#');
 while ((ch = infx[i++]) != '\0') {
  if (ch == '(')
   push(ch);
  else if (isalnum(ch))
   pofx[k++] = ch;
  else if (ch == ')') {
   while (s[top] != '(')
    pofx[k++] = pop();
   elem = pop(); /* Remove ( */
  } else { /* Operator */
   while (pr(s[top]) >= pr(ch))
    pofx[k++] = pop();
   push(ch);
  }
 }
 while (s[top] != '#') /* Pop from stack till empty */
  pofx[k++] = pop();
 pofx[k] = '\0'; /* Make pofx as valid string */
 printf("\n\nGiven Infix Expn: %s  Postfix Expn: %s\n", infx, pofx);
}
```

I try to implement math pow, but it doesnt work, can you help me? How can I implement? For example input is: `(1-5)^2^3`, and output is `15-2^3^` but it is wrong, the correct output is `15-23^^`

I think, that error is in method  int pr(char elem) , can you help me more?

Comment: Lots of algorithms for reverse polish notation - just google it

Comment: Why should I download something I do not understand? I understand this.
Thank you for the helpful advice.

Comment: It is the algorithm that you require. There is a good explanation on wikipedia

Comment: Thanks for the link, of course I read it on the wiki, but I can not implement it,...

Comment: Can you explain this? "Here is my code", but you forgot to remove the link to http://www.c-program-example.com/2011/10/c-program-for-infix-to-postfix.html

Comment: I have not forgotten to remove the link, I did not say that the code is my link I left on purpose, this code I found on the internet and I passed him and he understood.

I see about the council confess, only propositions like children.

Comment: What?  I don't understand any of this.

Comment: MARTIN: I'm trying to implement the code in diseases(pow) of the above, and please visitors to the forum for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem does *not* lie in `int pr(char elem)`, as it is a very simple function that only returns the precedence value for an operator. It's more subtle than that:

Numbers (and actually alphabetic characters as well) get 'pushed' immediately into `pofx`. Parentheses and operators need to be temporarily saved on a stack of their own: `s`. Only at the end of a string, or when a *higher* precedence operator is encountered, the operators currently on their own stack need to get added to `pofx`:

```
./infix "(1-5)+2*3"
pushing number '1'
pushing operator '-' (top is ()
pushing number '5'
resolving parentheses
pushing operator '+' (top is #)
pushing number '2'
pushing operator '*' (top is +)
pushing number '3'
Postfix Expn: 15-23*+
```

The original code checks for "higher-or-*equal*" precedence:

```
.. /* Operator */
   while (pr(s[top]) >= pr(ch))
```

Given the part `..^2^3`, the sequence of pushing is

```
^ - operator, #4 -> push on operand stack
2 - digit -> push immediately
^ - operator, #4 -> operand stack is '^' which is *equal*, so move to output stack
    and push next operand
3 - digit -> push immediately
.. end of input, move operand stack ('^' only) to end of output
```

If you change the comparison to this it will work correct:

```
while (pr(s[top]) > pr(ch))
```

Comment: You're welcome! I hope this also explained the *general* algorithm for you. (Suggestion: can you change your title to something else than "disease"? It seems a mistranslation crept in.)

Comment: (I edited my comment) - Yes, its work, and what abou this example input: 3+4*2/(1-5)^2^3, output: 3 4 2 1 5 - 2 3 ^ ^ / * +, but correct output is 3 4 2 * 1 5 − 2 3 ^ ^ / +

Comment: That is because `*` and `/` currently have the same precedence. If you change `*` to return a higher precedence than `/`, you'll get the correct output.

Comment: Thank you, i change, but I get always the same-bad output...


int pr(char elem) { /* Function for precedence */
 switch (elem) {
 case '#':
  return 0;
 case '(':
  return 1;
 case '+':
 case '-':
  return 2;
 case '/':
  return 3;
 case '*':
  return 4;
 case '^':
  return 5;
 }
}

Comment: Your new function `pr` is correct but I cannot duplicate that result. Using your original code and with my change and the new `pr` function, I get the correct result.

Comment: Heh, NOW its work, i dont no, where was problem, and now its ok, than you verry much! (its projekt to school, .. draw math function) :)

Than you Jongware, bye :-)